# Как засунуть переменную в строку?

Tags: lua

У меня (Условно) есть переменная `text = "Hello"`.

И мне нужно сделать так: `print("text World")`.

Я понимаю, что правильно делать так: `print(text, " World")`.
Но у меня функция принимает один аргумент.

Как засунуть переменную в строку?

Comment: `text .. " строка"`, `string.format("%s мир","привет")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в приведённом примере достаточно и конкатенации строк:

```
> st="привет"            
> st .. " мир"
привет мир
```

если же надо подставить строку в определённое место другой строки:

```
> st="привет"
> string.format("да %s мир", st)
да привет мир
```